# Basic JavaScript Project Task Modal Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been a web developer for nearly 15 years, mostly backend PHP stuff and dabbled with frontend over all those years.

Here recently the last few years I find myself building more and more with JavaScript so I have put an effort towards learning better.

I am building a Project Management app now and the code below is part of a section that will open a click on Task record into a popup Modal window.

A Task Modal allows edit-in-place task fields, an AJAX loaded comments/events panel, custom scrollbar DIVs, Date picker calendars, custom alerts, and more.

So There is a LOT going on in the Task Modal code.

There is literally a million ways to code a JavaScript app.  I seem to prefer this style below for most of my recent apps...

It is clean to read and easy to follow and understand.  I saw an example design pattern tonight that is just like my code below and the are calling it a `Facade`.  I never thought this was a Facade but maybe it is?

I have a LOT to learn still.

My question is about the mockup code below, it was over 1,000 lines and I removed 90% of it for this demo and post as my question is simple....

Inside of other functions in my code, I can access a `cached` selector or variable like this: `projectTaskModal.cache.NAME`

My question is, since the `cache` section is not a function, when my code is ran, are the `DOM Elements` I am trying to cache, are they even called/cached?

In other part of my app I have functions which are called which then execute the code within but this cache section has no function call.  SO I am not sure if on page load, if these value would be set or not?

If not, how would you suggest I go about mass-caching selectors?

Sorry this question might not be great, i've been awake 48 hours~

```
var projectTaskModal = {


    // Turn ON/OFF Console and Alert Debug Messages
    projectDebugConsole: true, //true;
    projectDebugAlert: false, //true;


    // Cache some values for use across the Application
    cache: {
        taskId: $('#Task-id'),
        projectId: $('#Task-project-id'),

        isTaskModalOpen: false,
        isAjaxRequestPending: false,

        updateTaskUrlEndpoint: '/updatetask',
        getTaskEventsUrlEndpoint: '/gettaskevents',
        createTaskCommentUrlEndpoint: '/createtaskcomment',
        getTaskStatusOptionsEndpoint: '/getTaskStatusOptions',

        taskStatusArray: [null, 'Not Started', 'In Progress', 'Completed'],
        taskStatusColorArray: [null, '#488ABC', '#8DC23C', '#D46060'],
        taskStatusCssClassArray: [null, 'not-started', 'in-progress', 'completed'],

        taskEventsContainer: $('#Task-events-inner-wrap'),
        //var loadingDiv: $('#task-row-1414135033730'),
        loadingDivSpinner: $('#Task-events-wrap'),
        loadingDivSpinnerImg: $('#task-events-loader-img'),
        loadingDivBackground: $('.Activity'),
        taskStatus: 'Completed',

    },


    init: function() {
        projectTaskModal.events.init();
        projectTaskModal.events.editInPlaceFieldSaveEvents();
        projectTaskModal.mockAjax.init();
        projectTaskModal.debug.log('ProjectTaskModal Init() Function Ran');
    },

};



// Run Task Modal Application
$(function() {
    projectTaskModal.init();
});
```

Comment: since the cache properties are not inside a function, they will be executed/initialized even before init is called. I assumed since page load would not have happened, cache.taskId, cache.projectId etc will be empty. You should set these dom specific properties of cache in init methods so you know they are set properly.

Comment: @gp. Thanks that makes sense now!  I'm doing some major re-organizing structuring now so that helps a lot!  I am going to add a `loadTaskModalData()` function so maybe I can populate them in there.  Right now it loads Task data from a Task list as all the data is in the DOM but I am going to make it more flexible and able to load Task data using AJAX and use the current DOM method so that the Task modal can be ran on pages that don't have the Task List in the DOM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making the `projectTaskModal` declaration a function:

```
var projectTaskModal = function() { 
    return {
        // Turn ON/OFF Console and Alert Debug Messages
        projectDebugConsole: true, //true;
        projectDebugAlert: false, //true;

        // Cache some values for use across the Application
        cache: {
            taskId: $('#Task-id'),
            projectId: $('#Task-project-id'),
            // snip for brevity
        },


        init: function() {
            projectTaskModal.events.init();
            projectTaskModal.events.editInPlaceFieldSaveEvents();
            projectTaskModal.mockAjax.init();
            projectTaskModal.debug.log('ProjectTaskModal Init() Function Ran');
        },

    };
};
```

Then later:

```
$(function() { 
    projectTaskModal = projectTaskModal();
    projectTaskModal.init();
});
```

This ensures the selector caches will be pointing to elements that depend on the DOM being ready. This line:

```
projectTaskModal = projectTaskModal();
```

replaces the function with the object returned by `projectTaskModal()`, which is the same as before otherwise.

Comment: Interesting, thanks this looks nice as it seems I can still keep my whole app in the same format/structure that I'm used to and it is simple wrapped with a  function, nice!